# CSS how to separate items when overflow

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to do message application like in image but I don't know how can I separate two blocks in same area. I will be glad if you help.

Here is an example:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.Grid {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  background-color: black;
}

.Sender {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  justify-self: start;
  background-color: white;
}

.Receiver {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  justify-self: end;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Sender">1</div>
  <div class="Receiver">2</div>
  <div class="Sender">3</div>
  <div class="Receiver">4</div>
  <div class="Sender">5</div>
  <div class="Receiver">6</div>
  <div class="Sender">7</div>
  <div class="Receiver">8</div>
  <div class="Sender">9</div>
  <div class="Receiver">10</div>
  <div class="Sender">11</div>
  <div class="Receiver">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Are there always 12 elements or are they generated dynamically and the number could differ?

Comment: Thanks. It changes dynamically. 12 is the limit per block. It must be continue like that: https://ibb.co/5FM8rCs

Comment: But in that image from your last comment the limit seemes to be ten?

Comment: It's not limit. Ignore that.

Comment: You could do that with `grid-areas` but that would also be static. I think for dynamic content you need JavaScript, independent if you want 5 or 6 items in one grid block...

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code and let me know if it helps

**Watch in "Full page" mode to see the effect.**

```css
.Grid {
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}

.Sender {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  justify-self: start;
  background-color: white;
}

.Receiver {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  justify-self: end;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Sender">1</div>
  <div class="Receiver">2</div>
  <div class="Sender">3</div>
  <div class="Receiver">4</div>
  <div class="Sender">5</div>
  <div class="Receiver">6</div>
</div>
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Sender">7</div>
  <div class="Receiver">8</div>
  <div class="Sender">9</div>
  <div class="Receiver">10</div>
  <div class="Sender">11</div>
  <div class="Receiver">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but not like that exactly. I want to do that one block. I mean there must be one Grid class.